# Comprometerse a

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Según la siguiente frase:

> ¿Todavía recuerdas **a** lo que te comprometiste al principio?

1. ¿Por qué necesita "a" aquí?
2. ¿Es correcto que sola uso "al principio"?
   (Hay persona preguntó [*"al principio" ¿de qué? No está claro.*] )

Answer (score 4):

Esto es debido a que "comprometer" se utiliza con la preposición "a".  Por ejemplo:

> Yo me comprometo a estudiar japonés por lo menos una vez a la semana.
>
> Él se compromete a pagar los gastos de la casa.

Por lo tanto cuando en una pregunta debe contener la preposición "a":

> ¿A qué te comprometes?

"al principio", como comentas, no está claro el "de que" pero se puede entender por el contexto, así que es completamente válido si existe el contexto que haga entender de lo que se está hablando.

Comment: "al principio" in English means "at first", only referring to the concept of time. Isn't it already clear?